# Cachet on Kubernetes APP_KEY Error

Tags: postgresql, docker, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-stackdriver

I'm trying to run the open source cachet status page within Kubernetes via this tutorial https://medium.com/@ctbeke/setting-up-cachet-on-google-cloud-817e62916d48

2 docker containers (cachet/nginx) and Postgres are deployed to a pod on GKE but the cachet container fails with the following CrashLoopBackOff error
[image: Crash error]

Within the [docker-compose.yml file](https://github.com/CachetHQ/Docker/blob/master/docker-compose.yml) its set to APP_KEY=${APP_KEY:-null} and i’m wondering if I didn’t set an environment variable I should have.

[image: Stack driver logs]

Any help with configuring the cachet docker file would be much appreciated! https://github.com/CachetHQ/Docker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to generate a key.

In the `entrypoint.sh` you can see that the bash script generates a key for you:

https://github.com/CachetHQ/Docker/blob/master/entrypoint.sh#L188-L193

It seems there's a bug in the Dockerfile here. Generate a key manually and then set it as an environment variable in your manifest.

There's a helm chart you can use in development here: https://github.com/apptio/helmcharts/blob/cachet/devel/cachet/templates/secrets.yaml#L12